# terra: go back from data.frame to raster object (inverse of as.data.frame(x, cell=TRUE)

Tags: r, raster, terra

Given:

```
library(terra)
r <- rast( extent=c( -108, -105, 39, 42 ), ncol=14, nrow=14, crs="epsg:4326" )
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
x <- c(r, r*2, r*3, r*0.5)
x.df <- as.data.frame(x, cell=TRUE)
head(x.df)
```

Assuming I do some changes in x.df, how can I go back
to a SpatRaster? In other words, which is
the inverse of as.data.frame()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your example data

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.17
r <- rast( extent=c( -108, -105, 39, 42 ), ncol=14, nrow=14, crs="epsg:4326" )
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
x <- c(r, r*2, r*3, r*0.5)
x.df <- as.data.frame(x)
```

You can do

```
n <- setValues(x, x.df)
```

The situation is different if the data.frame does not have values (rows) for all cells. But if you have the cell values

```
x.df <- as.data.frame(x, cell=TRUE)
```

you can do

```
z <- rast(x)
z[x.df$cell] <- x.df[,-1]
```

Comment: Does not work with terra 1.6.47 ```> z[x.df$cell] <- x.df[,-1]
Error: [rcl] if one argument is a list, the others should be a list,
       or a vector of length 1, or have the length of the list argument
```

Comment: works again with terra 1.6.51

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the hint is in help(rast)

```
xy <- xyFromCell(x, x.df$cell)
x2.df <- data.frame(x=xy[,1], y=xy[,2], x.df[,-1])
x2 <- rast(x2.df, type="xyz")
crs(x2) <- crs(x1)
```

It would be easier if as.data.frame() had options xy=TRUE and rowcol=TRUE

Comment: `as.data.frame<SpatRaster>` *has* argument `xy=FALSE`, but using that is not the best choice in this context